# Locking of 480 nm laser using EIT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, experimental-physics, laser

I am trying to lock 480 nm laser using EIT by frequency modulation technique. For this I have modulated the probe beam using 10 MHz phase modulated EOM, and trying to observe sidebands both right and left hand side of EIT signal. But I am not able to see sidebands ob oscilloscope. Bandwidth of our photodetector is also from DC to 200 MHz. Can anybody suggest how can I observe sidebands across EIT signal?

Comment: Can you add more information about your setup? It is not possible to know what the problem may be if, for example, there is a missing mixer or something in the path, can you add a diagram of your optical and electrical paths?